# Make element inside ListView immune to elastic scroll

Tags: listview, reactjs, scroll, react-native

I have a sub-header at the top of a `ListView`.
I want it to scroll along with the rest of the view when the user scrolls down, but I want it to stay still when the user is already at the top of the `ListView` and scrolls up, thus triggering the elastic scroll.

```
<ListView
    ...
    renderHeader={() => this.renderHeader()}
    ...
/>

renderHeader() {
    return (
       <View style={styles.header}>
           <SubHeader/> // should be immune to elastic scroll
           <OtherStuff/>
       </View>
    )
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without wrapping the `SubHeader` inside an `<Animated>` and applying a `transformY` which would be the inverse of the scroll value, which I specifically try to avoid for performance reasons?

Thanks!